# My "toggle class" javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am using this little script to toggle classes of an element on click of another element. Here is the stripped down code:

```
//Toggle comments
function togglecomments() {
    function shiftcomments() {
        var comments = document.getElementsByTagName('aside')[0];
        if(comments.className = "hide"){comments.className = "show";}
        else{comments.className = "hide";};
    }
    var commenttoggle = document.getElementById('toggle-comments');
    bindEvt(commenttoggle, "click", shiftcomments);


}
bindEvt(window, "load", togglecomments);
```

The thing is it works once, but after that on click the class does not toggle anymore. For those interested here is the event handler I use: http://pastebin.com/md3dPvMJ (It worked fine before so it shouldn't be the problem.)

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks for your feedback guys!

Comment: Just a crazy guess, you're new to javascript?

Comment: You are missing an equal sign at the if statement. 1 equal is for assignment (eg: `myvar = 1;`) and 2 or 3 for comparison (eg: `if (myvar == 1) ...`).

Comment: @MikeRobinson Yes indeed any suggestions to improve my code? :p

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript equality, get ready to lose some hair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statements you've got this:

```
if(comments.className = "hide")
```

It should be:

```
if(comments.className === "hide")
```

This would also work:

```
if(comments.className == "hide")
```

What you are actually doing up there is changing the className to "hide", not checking for equality.

For the difference between `==` and `===` I'll actually point you to another question here at stackoverflow: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little function I'm using, with jQuery, but it can be updated.

```
        toggleClass = function (obj, className) {
            var currentClass = $(obj).attr('class'),
                hasIt = false;
            if (currentClass.indexOf(className) < 0) {
                currentClass += " " + className;
                hasIt = true;
            } else {
                currentClass = currentClass.replace(className, "");
                hasIt = false;
            }

            $(obj).attr('class', currentClass);
            return hasIt;
        };
```

Comment: The problem with index of would be that it doesn't stop on words. Example: HTML: `<div class="someclazz">`. If you call toggleClass with `className=clazz` the `indexOf` would return >=0 and this would result in `<div class="some">`.

Comment: That is if you don't namespace your classes.